# Stack returns wrong item on calling pop()

Tags: java, list, stack

I'm using **Stack** class for pushing `List<Integer>` and popping the item again back from stack:

```
Stack<List<Integer>> mStack = new Stack<>();

public void pushToStack(View view){
    List<Integer> mSearchResults = new ArrayList<>();
    for(int i=0; i< 10;i++){
        mSearchResults.add(i);
    }
    Log.d(TAG,"Pushing item: " + mSearchResults.size());
    mStack.push(mSearchResults);

    Log.d(TAG,"Clearing list");
    mSearchResults.clear();
    Log.d(TAG,"Size after clearing : " + mSearchResults.size());
}
```

I'm clearing the list after pushing to stack.

The pushToStack function outputs the logs :

*Pushing item: 10*

*Clearing list*

*Size after clearing : 0*

```
public void popFromStack(View view){
    if(mStack.size() == 0){
        Log.d(TAG,"Stack is Empty");
    }else{
        List<Integer> searchResults = mStack.pop();
        Log.d(TAG,"Result size after pop: " + searchResults.size());
    }
}
```

and popFromStack prints the log:

*Result size after pop: 0*

I wonder why mStack.pop() returns 0 as list item size instead 10.

What am I doing wrong here ?

Comment: You're pushing a list on the stack, and clearing that list. Why do you expect the list not to be cleared? If you put a bottle in a room, then empty that bottle, then get the bottle out of the room, it will be empty, won't it?

Comment: @JBNizet java passes method arguments by value not by reference. Isn't it ?

Comment: The value that it passes *is* a reference. Any non-primitive variable or parameter is a *reference* to an object. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40523/4125191).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The stack does not return the wrong item on calling pop().  The stack returns the right item.  You can verify this with the following:

```
Log.d( TAG, "list: " + System.identityHashCode( searchResults ) );
Log.d( TAG, "list: " + System.identityHashCode( mSearchResults ) );
```

What happens is that a `Stack<List<Integer>>` contains items which are of type `List<Integer>` which is an ***Object*** type.  In java objects are always accessed by reference, which means that a `Stack<List<Integer>>` contains ***references*** to list of integer.

This in turn means that when you modify the list, the stack will continue to hold a reference to it, so whatever changes you perform on the list will be visible.

Essentially, the `push` operation did *not* make a copy of the list; it just stored a reference to the one and only list that you have onto the stack.

Answer (score 0):

So, this is what the program is doing:

1. Adds 10 elements in a list
2. Pushes that list into a Stack
3. Clears the list
4. Pops the element from the stack and checks the size

Now, in step 2, Stack already has a reference of that list, when it gets cleared in step 3, the reference then has a list with 0 elements.
So, in step 4, same (empty) list gets retrieved back and hence, `sysout` prints 0.

If you want that stack to retain old list then you can do

```
mSearchResults = new ArrayList<>();
```

instead of

```
mSearchResults.clear();
```